# How to not pick up a record that have a priority based on columns names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

One of the column Im picking up is `PolicyType` and the condition for that is  `TransactionType = 'Policy'`.
But sometimes the same `Insured`can have same `TransactionType` value but different `PolicyType` value. So if I have the same insured with same `TransactionType` but different `PolicyType` - how can prioritize and  choose the record that has PolicyType`='Rewrite'`and ignore  the one with`PolicyType='New Business'`?
Should be simple `CASE` statement but I am confused 
[image]

```
SELECT   CAST(YEAR(EffectiveDate) as CHAR(4))+'/'+ CAST(MONTH(EffectiveDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS YearMonth,
         Insured, 
        PolicyNumber,
        EffectiveDate,
        PolicyType,
        TransactionType,
        SUM(Premium) as Premium,
        ExperienceMod,
        ISNULL(ScheduleMod,0) as ScheduleMod,
        TerritoryMod,
        ISNULL(EffectiveMod,0) as EffectiveMod

FROM ProductionReportMetrics
WHERE EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE())
        AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company' AND Insured <>'Jerry''s Test' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' --and  PolicyNumber ='ZAWCI2517900'
GROUP BY Insured,
        PolicyNumber,
        PolicyType,
        TransactionType,
        EffectiveDate,
        experienceMod,ScheduleMod,TerritoryMod,EffectiveMod, Premium,EffectiveDate
ORDER BY YEAR(EffectiveDate), (MONTH(EffectiveDate)), PolicyType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your sample data, I suppose the priority for the `policyType` column is `rewrite > renewal > new business`. :)

Therefore here comes the solution, please change the code accordingly:

```
--Create table
create table #test (id int identity(1,1), name varchar(10), trantype varchar(10) default 'policy', policytype varchar(50))

--insert sample data
insert #test (name,trantype,policytype)
select 'abc','policy','new business'
union all
select 'abc','policy','rewrite'
union all
select 'AA','policy','new business'
union all
select 'BB','policy','new business'
union all
select 'BB','policy','rewrite'
union all
select 'CC','policy','rewrite'

select * from #test

--solution
select * from 
(select *, row_number()over(partition by name,trantype order by policytype desc) as rid 
 from #test
) as b
where b.rid = 1
```

**RESULT:**

(1)If only `new business` was there for a specified `insured`, then it will be selected;

(2)If both `new business` and `rewrite` are there for a certain `insured`, then only rewrite will be selected.

[image]